# Committing a container on windows breaks python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

A strange python script failure happens when running the python script through `docker run`

**Circumstances:**
I have an image(was built on linux) which contains a simple python file named `/opt/test.py` with permission of `-rwxr-xr-x`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os import mkdir
print("hello world")
```

**Running the script in the original image**

- stepping into the image (`docker run -it --entrypoint bash myimage`) then run: `bash-4.4# /opt/test.py`
  result:  `hello world`
- using docker run: `docker run myimage /opt/test.py` result: `hello world`

**Modify the image in the following way**

- commit the container without any change on windows `docker commit container_id newimage`

**Running the script in the new image**

- stepping into the image (`docker run -it --entrypoint bash newimage`) then run: `bash-4.4# /opt/test.py`
  result:  `hello world`  
  so far so good...
- using docker run: `docker run newimage /opt/test.py`
  result: `/opt/test.py: line 2: from: command not found'`

This error means that the OS don't know how to run the file, thats why we have to provide the python command as `#!/usr/bin/python3`  Which we already did.
 The permission is still `-rwxr-xr-x` 
And as you can see it can run the script successfully when you step into the container created from the image.

Comment: Is the last command shown wrong? Did you mean to show `docker run --rm newimage /opt/test.py` ?

Comment: @Paolo
Thanks, my mistake. Yes I ran it on the newimage. Fixed the code.

Comment: Where did the original `myimage` come from?  Can you provide a Dockerfile or another reproducible path to create the image?  (Using `docker commit` is very rarely a best practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker commit has a magical property- it carries over all of the properties on an existing container to the new image.

You did `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash`

This means that when you do `docker run newimage /some/file.py` you are executing that file AS A SHELL SCRIPT. And, generally, python scripts don't work very well in bash. The equivalent is `/bin/bash /opt/test.py`

Read your error message- its literally saying that there's a syntax error on line 2 of /opt/test.py

Answer (score 0):

I managed to 'solve' this, however I still  don't understand the behaviour behind this.

The keypoint is how the container was created from which we commit the new image

1.**Committing a container which was created by stepping into in it**
(like docker run -it --entrypoint bash myimage) **will break the image**
2.Committing a container which was created by any other way (like docker run myimage /some_command) won't break it

Comment: all of your `docker run` commands have `--rm` ... what command are you using to create the container you're committing?

Comment: @Becotte thanks fixed, I dont have those ofcz.. just copypasted them from different context.